# Play Framework Project: How to include plugin from source

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

Background:
I am in the process of integrating TypeScript into a Play Framework (2.2.6) and I am trying to use mumoshu's plugin to do so. Problem is, the plugin has problems when running "play dist" on a windows machine.
I've forked the code from GitHub in order to make some modifications to the source so I can continue using the plugin.

Question:
I have a play framework plugin in the traditional source structure:

```
project/build.properties
project/Build.scala
project/plugins.sbt
src/main/scala/TypeScriptPlugin
src/main/scala/TypeScriptKeys.scala
...<other code>
```

I'd like to include this plugin into another project but I don't really know where to start and how to hookup the settings.

From previous suggestions, I've been able to add the module to my project as follows:

```
// In project/Build.scala...
object ApplicationBuild extends Build{
    lazy val typeScriptModule = ProjectRef(file("../../../play2-typescript"), "play2-typescript")

    lazy val main = play.Project(<appName>, <appVersion>, <appDependencies>).settings(typescriptSettings: _*).dependsOn(typeScriptModule).aggregate(typeScriptModule)
}
```

Where `typescriptSettings` is defined in the other project... I think, I'm still not 100% sure what typescriptSettings IS other than adding this settings call enabled the plugin to work. This worked fine originally when I had included the plugin in the `plugins.sbt` file and imported the package `com.github.mumoshu.play2.typescript.TypeScriptPlugin._` but now that I'm including the source and explicitly including the module, I can't just import the package... Or at least not the way I used to.

I am still new to scala/sbt and I am having difficulty finding helpful resources online. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming in the same parent directory you have two directories:

- `play2-typescript`: which is a clone of [mumoshu's play2-typescript](https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-typescript)
- `play2-typescript-testapp`: which is the play app in which you're testing your changes

You need to create, inside `play2-typescript-testapp`'s `project` directory a file like so:

**play2-typescript.sbt**

```
val metaBuild = (project in file(".")
  dependsOn ProjectRef(file("../../play2-typescript"), "play2-typescript")
)
```

---

**Note:**

The relative path is to the `play2-typescript` plugin project, and is relative to the `project` directory inside `play2-typescript-testapp`.

Change that to what is correct in your setup, and consider that you can also define it as an absolute path.

Comment: This seems to build fine but I don't know how to set any of the settings for the included module. Again, still getting used to the SBT setup.

Comment: For example, I previously set the plugin setting through the root project
.settings(typescriptSettings: _*)
I think I still need to do that for it to work, but not sure how to set it.

Comment: absolutely, this is just making your test app setup depend on the sources of your fork of the plugin, after that you do everything like normal: configure your play project in build.sbt at the root of the test app.

Comment: And that's the thing that is confusing. I was using .settings(typescriptSettings: _*) in the Build.scala file but it can't find typescriptSettings because it's defined in the other project. However, I can't import the package defined in that project either. I'll update the description of the problem to better reflect my "test" project.

Comment: So I solved the problem. The problem was that the Project needed to be loaded into the plugins.sbt file like so:
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(typescript)
lazy val typescript = file("../modules/typescript");

Given this load, I was able to import the proper external packages and configure the proper settings in the Build.Scala file. 

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: oh interesting you used dependsOn the file instead of with ProjectRef. Thanks for feeding back.

Answer (score 0):

There a lots of activator template examples of this. I have a project where we followed the https://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-multidomain-auth path. Specifically, to address your question; the plugins in the root project play-multidomain-auth/project/ are accessible in the modules (play-multidomain-auth/modules/admin/, .../common, and .../web).

This example is the cleanest example I've seen in using multi-project design however that opinion is very subjective.

I hope this helps.